# Read specific value from csv and append the value last column of same row

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to read value health policy number from "column1"  of a excel csv file, search the document for same policy on the a web portal, copy the name and append in the "column2"  of the respective policy number. Not writing entire code just the code which is working      fine.

```
import csv

try:
 csvfile1 = open("E:\\Test.csv", "r")

 r = csv.reader(csvfile1)
 next(r, None)
 for row in r:
     policy_number = row[0]
     print policy_number

 #here Code to get the doc name from web page for each policy row

     Pdf_docName="doc1.pdf"

except Exception as e:
 print ("There is Issue in reading the CSV ---------",format(e))
```

Expected Output

In put Column 1:-

```
Policy32456,  
Policy89765,  
Policy00034,
```

Output Column 2:-

```
doument1.pdf,  
doument2.pdf,  
doument3.pdf,
```